# If workbook contains 6 tabs then run current Sub, if workbook contains 9 tabs then run a different Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that houses the macro which loops through a directory of 800+ workbooks while taking particular cells and copying them to this workbook.  It has worked fine for 2 years until 50 of the 800+ workbooks were changed from 6 tabs to 9 tabs.

I have `For X = 6 To Wb2.Sheets.Count` which is throwing the debug error because the new workbooks have 9 tabs.

I have 2 separate codes that need to run to pull those cells depending if the workbook has 6 or 9 tabs and need help.

Here is my working full Sub, any suggestions on how to do this would be a major help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim L As Long, X As Long
    spath = "c:\attachments\"
    sfile = Dir(spath & "*.xls*")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set WS = Sheets.Add(before:=Sheets(1))

    L = 1
        Do While sfile <> ""
            Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(spath & sfile)

            For X = 6 To Wb2.Sheets.Count

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "B").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Daily_Revenue_Management").Range("C33").Value

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "C").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Daily_Revenue_Management").Range("D3").Value

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "D").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("D4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "E").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("D5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "F").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("D6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "G").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("D7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "H").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("D8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "I").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("E4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "J").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("E5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "K").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("E6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "L").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("E7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "M").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("E8").Value

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "N").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("G4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "O").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("G5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "P").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("G6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "Q").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("G7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "R").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("G8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "S").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("H4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "T").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("H5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "U").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("H6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "V").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("H7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "W").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("H8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "X").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("I4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "Y").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("I5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "Z").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("I6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AA").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("I7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AB").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("I8").Value

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AC").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("L4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AD").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("L5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AE").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("L6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AF").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("L7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AG").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("L8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AH").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("M4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AI").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("M5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AJ").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("M6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AK").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("M7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AL").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("M8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AM").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("N4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AN").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("N5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AO").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("N6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AP").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("N7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AQ").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("N8").Value

Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AR").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("Q4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AS").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("Q5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AT").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("Q6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AU").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("Q7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AV").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("Q8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AW").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("R4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AX").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("R5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AY").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("R6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "AZ").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("R7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BA").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("R8").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BB").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("S4").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BC").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("S5").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BD").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("S6").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BE").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("S7").Value
Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "BF").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Rolling 4month Snapshot").Range("S8").Value

    L = L + 1
        Next
            Wb2.Close False
            sfile = Dir()
        Loop
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    If L > 0 Then
End If


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B1:B1000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("data").Visible = True
Sheets("data").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("data").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Updated: " & Format(Date, "MM/DD/YYYY")
Range("A6").Select

UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: Uh ... `if thisworkbook.worksheets.count = 9 then`

Comment: What's the purpose of the loop? It seems to run the exact same values transfers multiple times....  Why use a loop at all:? previously (with 6 sheets) it would have just run *once*, and that's all you need I think.  Also consider using a couple of variables to reduce the volume of code you have there.

Comment: ThisWorkbook is not the issue, it's the opening of 800+ other workbooks in a directory that has either 6 of 9 worksheets in the workbook.  That is what I am struggling on

Comment: @TimWilliams - there's a `L = L + 1` in there but I don't know what it is intended to do.

Comment: Incrementing `L` just moves the destination one row down for each file

Comment: The 800+ workbooks are identical in nature (except for the new change made to 50 of them)  The code pulls the exact cells from each 800+ workbooks and stacks their data on a single sheet where it reads to summarize the 800+ reports.

Comment: As noted, you could do `If WB2.Worksheets.Count = 6 Then`. Also, why use `X = 6 to WB2.Worksheets.Count`. I though the worksheet count was 6? This loop would never run.

Comment: Also, from what I can tell, X is never used anyways, and it looks as though you are just copying static rows. What is the point of the Loop?

Comment: Like this? and then apply to all the other lines?           If Wb2.Worksheets.Count = 6 Then
        Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "B").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Daily_Revenue_Management").Range("C33").Value
    If Wb2.Worksheets.Count = 9 Then
        Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "B").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Competitive Pricing").Range("J8").Value

Comment: The `X` loop is pointless - it does nothing and could be safely removed

Comment: @DDO - *please* explain exactly what the difference is between the 6- and 9-sheet workbooks.  What different action(s)  do you need to take depending on the sheet count?

Comment: I pull data points from the exact same cells on 800+ workbooks, those workbooks all are identical, just different data and all have 6 tabs.  The designer of that report decided to make a revision but added more tabs and the data is in different cells that I need to pull, which I have the new locations for. The trouble is I need to tell it to pull these listed cells if the report in the directory has 6 tabs, or if it is the new version (9 tabs), I need to tell it to pull different cells.  The L is used to stack the data points so my excel formulas summarize (each file gets it's own row)

Comment: This is working....I removed
For X = 6 To Wb2.Sheets.Count
and added to each line
    If Wb2.Worksheets.Count = 6 Then
        Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "B").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Daily_Revenue_Management").Range("C33").Value
    ElseIf Wb2.Worksheets.Count = 9 Then
        Wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(L, "B").Value = Wb2.Sheets("Competitive Pricing").Range("J8").Value
    End If
I took out the Next towards the end too.
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the commenters, the "X" loop doesn't make sense.  But to put different rows depending on the number of sheets:

```
If Wb2.Sheets.Count = 6 then
  'code for 6-sheet workbook
Elseif Wb2.Sheets.Count = 9 then
  'code for 9-sheet workbook
End if
```